# Computer Graphics Previous Year Question asked in UGC NET 2021

Tags: transformations, matrix, coordinates

What is the transformation matrix M that transforms a square in the x-y plane defined by (1, 1)<sup>T</sup> (-1, 1)<sup>T</sup> (-1, -1)<sup>T</sup> (1, -1)<sup>T</sup> to a parallelogram whose corresponding vertices are (2, 1)<sup>T</sup> (0,1)<sup>T</sup> (-2, -1)<sup>T</sup> and (0, -1)<sup>T</sup> ? Following are options below. This is not a homework question.

[image]

I can easily find transformation matrix in 2X2 but how 3X3 ? I got confused between Option A and C. How third row and column is added ?

Comment: The 2x2 upper left matrix is a skew in both A and C, the third column adds a translation. In A the translation is 0,0 and in C the translation is 1,0.

Comment: So, out of A and C, which one is correct ? and Why ?

Comment: I think the entire point of this question is to get the reader to recognize that a 2x2 matrix can be pulled out and multiplied by the points. Doing that to just 1 point will yield the correct answer since that point with either need to be translated(C) or left as is(A). I highly recommend going through the exercise of multiplying the 2x2 matrix by the first point to get the answer to the question.